# How to compile reverse engineered android app?

Tags: android, dll, unity-game-engine, reverse-engineering

So I have an android game which is using unity, and I looked for scripts inside dll and know exactly what should I change in C# code, I mean I reverse engineered this app almost completely. What should I do next? Complile it? But how?

Comment: Prepare yourself to have **legal troubles**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use use AAPT (Android Asset Packaging Tool) to decompile-recompile apks.
For more information how to use it, below references are given:

http://elinux.org/Android_aapt

[What is aapt(Android Asset Packaging Tool) & How it works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234671/what-is-aaptandroid-asset-packaging-tool-how-it-works)

[ReverseEngineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4624/how-do-i-reverse-engineer-so-files-found-in-android-apks)

Comment: Somehow, good articles and good references, but did you try that yourself ?

Comment: Yes, I already tried aapt command using console and earlier I made a tool in VB.NET to decompile/recompile apk.
Here is link to my tool: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2043145

Comment: No, i mean, with a compiled android application which is written by android studio ?

Comment: I tried with a compiled android application which was written by Eclipse.

Comment: So, you haven't tried that with Android studio output, i should try that i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you can't do that with `Proguard Obfuscation` limit.! Especially, for ***Android applications*** which is written by `Android Studio`.

I mean, if one app compiled(for android studio f.g), `Progaurd` will do the `Obfuscation` and you can't even see the right codes.

Comment: The app which I am working on is not obfuscated, the code is clear, but I need to compile this app with slight changes of code. Is it possible to compile with android studio?

Comment: if you have experience with android programming, you can copy them and  creating a project for that and then change the values or addreses and compile it, otherwise, it's not directly possible!