# I Cant upload new apk in playstore and publish

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-console

When i try to upload new apk in playstore it says "You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 4" but there is no apk in apk library with version code 4 there is only 2 and 3. but I Changed the version code in build.gradle file to versionCode 5. but its shows the same error "You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 4.
"
I tried Clean Project,Rebuild Project and In-validate Cache/Restart but whatever I do the error message from google is same.

What would i do

Comment: Have you changed version name too?

Comment: yes, I changed and the version code is still 4

Comment: Can you share your defaultConfig code from Gradle

Comment: I Checked the version code using "aapt"

Comment: Go for edit release in play publish account it must be available there.

Comment: did you mean "build.gradle" file

Comment: "EDIT RELEASE" has only one option -->UPLOAD NEW APK

Comment: Is there any other way to chanage versionCode

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "svs.myapps.com.myapp1"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 5
        versionName "3.1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

Comment: @SarathSVS defaultConfig looks fine.

Comment: i found the problem, when i tried to generate a signed apk its just show "Generated Successfully" but there is no apk in the folder, i deleted the old "app-release.pk" and now i cant generate new one but it shows "Generated Successfully" with no apk in the folder message. Please Help Me

Comment: What  is wrong with "Android Studio" it Showing APk Generated Successfully but no apk in the specified folder

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are changing the (int) version code rather than just the version name. You can inspect the version code for an APK by doing:

`aapt dump badging foo.apk |grep version`

aapt can be found in `{sdk directory}/build-tools/{sdkversion}/`

More informations about aapt: [What is aapt(Android Asset Packaging Tool) & How it works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234671/what-is-aaptandroid-asset-packaging-tool-how-it-works)